# php write to file without prompting for download

Tags: php, file

The following code works fine for writing to a file, but I don't want it prompts the user to download whenever it executes.  I would like to prevent this... Any help would be appreciatied.  I've also tried it with fwrite with the same results.

```
$file_name = 'orders'.date('Ymd').'csv';
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
$data = array(
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"'
);

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) 
{
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Why using this? header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"'); if you don't want to let download the file?

Comment: Googled it and that was part of the code so I assumed it was necessary

Comment: @user1815207 It is necessary, they just don't know what `php://output` is.

Comment: The content type for an Excel BIFF file is `application/vnd.ms-excel`, not `application/excel`; and as you're sending a csv file it should really be `text/csv` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not possibility to do that (or even if there is some trick, you never should use it!).
Only way to avoid prompt is to change browser settings which of course can be done by user, not by you.

It'll not be safe for user if anybody would be able to save files on his computer without any prompt.

Comment: I was intending to write to the server... not anybody's computer.

Comment: @user1815207 So don't use `php://output` and use server file path. After that, remove lines with `header`.

Comment: I've been programming for around 13 hours and I don't write much php so some bad googling led me down this path

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lines

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
```

and it will just write the file.

As it is, it does not appear to be outputting any content anyhow.

Comment: He is writing to `php://output` so it'll output something :)

Comment: @Elon good point, I didn't even see that (thinking fopen meant writing to a file on disk...)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up how HTTP (headers in particular) works and local files.

The way a HTTP response is interpreted by the browser can be suggested by using headers (content-type, content-disposition).
The way a file is interpreted by your operating system and applications has nothing to do with HTTP and HTTP headers.

Your script basically does two things:

1. tells the browser (through HTTP headers) to interpret the response as an `application/excel` attachment (triggers download and passes responsibility to the operating system);
2. writes some stuff to a file.

You need to skip step (1).

Also, if you don't care about performance in special cases, [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) should be enoguh.